# Calling a method inside an IIFE exported method

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, es6-module-loader, esbuild

i have a script which i want to expose a function using JS Modules this script is compiled using esbuild.

pre-transpiled file (index.mjs)

```js
const NakamaWrapper = require("./nakama").default

var NakamaJS;

export default function InitNakama(host, port, useSSL) {
    NakamaJS = new NakamaWrapper(host, port, useSSL);
    NakamaJS.initiate();
}
```

esbuild task

```
"build-dev": "./node_modules/.bin/esbuild ./src/index.mjs --bundle --sourcemap --target=es2015 --outfile=./dist/dev/pc-nakama.js",
```

exported code (i notice the function is inside an IIFE)
[image]

code in the html:

```js
import * as NakamaJS from "./pc-nakama.js"; 
NakamaJS.InitNakama("192.168.100.50", 7350, false);
```

error:

```
NakamaJS.InitNakama is not a function
```

[the source of my project is here](https://github.com/zentyk/pc.nakama)

Comment: I'm not familiar with esbuild but if it works like other bundlers such as webpack then you need to also compile the importing script along with your module. This of course means that the importing script cannot be an html file, it must be a js file. The way these systems work assume that the html file only sources your scripts and does nothing else. You're supposed to do everything in js files.

Comment: it doesn't matter, i loaded a module outisde an IIFE from an html script tag and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output format defaults to `--format=iife` but you can use `--format=esm` to output in ECMAScript module format instead, which will work with `import`. Docs are here: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format-esm.